# How to delete TableViewCell that being a Dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, dictionary

I am trying to delete a table view cell using swipe to delete, but I can't use the line I marked in my code, not sure why. My cells are being made by a Dictionary, with the key for the title and the value for the details.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //Create the cell by the dictionary favDict
    for (key, value) in favDict{
        cell.textLabel?.text = key
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = value
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        favDict.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)// Line that is giving the error says Int is not convertible for [String: String]
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Resolution:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var dictKeys : [String]?

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        dictKeys = Array(favDict.keys)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        dictKeys = Array(favDict.keys)
        return rowsInSec
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var key = dictKeys?[indexPath.row]
        var data = favDict[key!]
        cell.textLabel?.text = key
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data

         return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
        {
            var key  = dictKeys?[indexPath.row]
            favDict.removeValueForKey(key!)
            dictKeys?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            rowsInSec--
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use;

```
favDict.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
```

`removeAtIndex` is a instance method of `NSMutableArray`. For removing value from dictionary you can use:

```
favDict.removeValueForKey("yourkey")
```

**EDIT:**

The removing and loading data using `Dictionary` is little bit hard compared to `NSMutableArray`. Also you put a loop in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` . It'll load only the last object to every cell.

If you are still looking for Dictionary, you can do it like:

Implement the methods like:

```
var dictKeys : [Strings]?
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dictKeys = Array(favDict.keys)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
   var key  = dictKeys?[indexPath.row]
   var data = favDict[key!]
   cell.textLabel?.text = key
   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data
   return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    {
        var key  = dictKeys?[indexPath.row]
        favDict.removeValueForKey(key!)
        dictKeys?.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, but will that delete the key too? And how will I know what key to use if I don't know what cell it is deleting?

Comment: @Skal: It'll remove the key also. The issue is you can't easily achieve the intended behaviour from NSDictionary. You need to use complex mechanism for finding the yourKey. If you still insist to keep dictionary, then I'll explain how.

Comment: I really need the dictionary otherwise I will not be able to achieve what I want. I would really appreciate if you explain me how to.

Comment: Something is not working, Xcode doesn't let me create "var dictKeys? = nil". And just a ad-on there is an extra curly braces in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Comment: @Skal: That was my mistake, use `var dictKeys : [Strings]?`

Comment: Dude it worked! Just to make sure if someone view this topic later, you need to reduce the numberOfRowsInSection before you delete the cell and is also missing a little bang: "favDict.removeValueForKey(key!)"

Comment: @Skal: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate it. How did you implemented the `numberOfRowsInSection` ? That depends on the reducing issue. If you are lively calculating the number of keys in dictionary then it's ok

Comment: I defined a `var rowsInSec = 0` them every time the user added a cell it would increase it by 1 them in the `numberOfRowsInSection` function I returned the `rowsInSec`

Comment: @Skal: Also you can do like `var count = dictKeys?.count
        return count!;`. I'm removing the key from the array when the row is deleted. Please check my update. So it'll also work. You need to write the same code written in viewDidLoad in the numberOfRowsInSection also (as the data is dynamically changing)

Comment: ooh wait, I was trying it here, I don't know how but the elements is not deleting, it is just removing the cell.

Comment: It is crashing when I try to delete:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'